# Downloading a file using an API with MVC in VB

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, download, get

I'm building an API with MVC in VB.  It has two Get methods in the controller, one to get the order number and year it was placed, the other to get the files pertaining to it and put them into an XML file.  I need to be able to download a file retrieved in the XML but I'm not sure if I need to build another Get method or something else.  Or should I try to retrieve the file outside of the XML. Any recommendations?

Here is my controller:

```
Public Class OrdersController
Inherits ApiController

'' GET api/values
'Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
'    Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
'End Function

'' GET api/values/5
'Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
'    Return "value"
'End Function

'' POST api/values
'Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

'End Sub

'' PUT api/values/5
'Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal value As String)

'End Sub

'' DELETE api/values/5
'Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal id As Integer)

'End Sub
<Route("orders/{id}")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetOrderYear(ByVal id As String) As ReturnVal
    Dim x As New SPFolderDB

    Return x.GetOrderInformation(id)
End Function

<Route("orders/{id}/contents")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetContents(ByVal id As String) As SPFolderOver
    Dim x As New SPFolderDB
    Dim retValue As ReturnVal = x.GetOrderInformation(id)
    Dim ex As Sharepoint = New Sharepoint()
    Dim t = ex.GetOrderContent(retValue.Year, retValue.SONumber)
    Dim myT = New SPFolderOver()
    myT = SPFolderOver.LoadFolder(t)
    Return myT
End Function
```

Comment: Are you hosting the content that you are going to download on your own website?

Comment: I'm pretty sure hosting won't be happening.  I'm still fairly new to coding so I apologize that I don't have a huge understanding of hosting.  Right now, the files that I'm trying to retrieve are Sharepoint objects, so I serialize them into XML and so far have tested my Get method with Postman to retrieve the XML but I'm not sure where to go from there.